# Prove if $F\in\mathcal{A}$, then we have $\bigcap\mathcal{A}\subseteq F \subseteq \bigcup\mathcal{A}$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

- Prove that if $F\in\mathcal{A}$, then we have

$$\bigcap\mathcal{A}\subseteq F \subseteq \bigcup\mathcal{A}$$.

Note: $\bigcap\mathcal{A}=\bigcap_{U\in\mathcal{A}}U$ and $\bigcup\mathcal{A}=\bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{A}}U$.

*My proof.* Let $F\in\mathcal{A}.$

$(\subseteq)$. Let $x\in\bigcap\mathcal{A}=\bigcap_{U\in\mathcal{A}}U$. It means that $x\in U$ for all $U\in\mathcal{A}$, so $x\in F$ because $F\in\mathcal{A}$. Hence

$$\bigcap\mathcal{A}\subseteq F.$$

$(\supseteq).$ $x\in\bigcup U$ iff there is a some $U\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $x\in A$. But $F$ is an exactly such an $U$.
**Can you check my proof?** Thankss...

Comment: First part: correct; remove only $x \in \bigcap \ldots$ (the final formula).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Second part correct?

Comment: May you check second part true?

Comment: As written, is quite useless... You can improve it using the def of $\bigcup$. $x \in \bigcup A \text { iff there is some } U \in A \text { such that } x \in A$. But $F$ is exactly such an $U$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for comments. I edited my answer.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I have a question: How should we say $F\in U$? How did you get it, can you explain?

Comment: may you see my last comment here?

Comment: Your proof is correct now.

Comment: @palmpo Thanks ...